# Pasar un arreglo dinamico por funcion en C++

Tags: c++

¿Me podrían ayudar con el siguiente ejercicio?

La idea es tener 3 funciones con 3 vectores, el vector 1 ingresa números pares, el vector 2 ingresa números impares y el vector 3 multiplica cada valor del vector 1 con el vector 2.
Al final se despliegan los 3 vectores.
El problema es que para el vector 3 no tengo como referenciar los vectores 1 y 2, y por lo tanto no realiza la multiplicación. Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using std::setw;

vectorpar (vector<int>numerospares) {
    int size1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        if (i % 2 ==0)
        numerospares.push_back(i);
    }
    size1 = numerospares.size();

    for(int j = 0; j< size1; j++) {
        cout << setw(3) << numerospares[j] << endl;
    }
}

vectorimpar (vector<int> numerosimpares) {
    int size2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        if (i % 2 !=0)
        numerosimpares.push_back(i);
    }
    size2 = numerosimpares.size();

    for(int j = 0; j< size2; j++) {
        cout << setw(3) << numerosimpares[j] << endl;
    }
}

parximpar (vector<int> paresximpares) {
    vector <int>numerospares;
    vector <int>numerosimpares;

    //int size3 = numerospares.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        vectorpar (numerospares)[i] * vectorimpar (numerosimpares)[i];
    }
}

int main() {
  vector <int>numerospares;
  vector <int>numerosimpares;
  vector <int>paresximpares;

  cout<<"El arreglo de pares es:"<<endl;
  vectorpar (numerospares);

  cout<<"El arreglo de impares es:"<<endl;
  vectorimpar (numerosimpares);

  cout<<"El producto de los arreglos es:"<<endl;
  vectorparximpar (paresximpares);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A parte de que te falta el tipo de retorno de las funciones (como no devuelven nada deben ser `void`) deberás pasar los vectores por referencia:

```
void vectorpar (vector<int> &numerospares);

void vectorimpar (vector<int> &numerosimpares);

void parximpar (vector<int> &paresximpares);
```

Como estás pasando por copia los vectores, los datos se quedan dentro de la función, para que la función pueda modificar un vector que está definido fuera de la misma (y de esta manera los datos puedan *salir* de la misma), debe recibirlo por referencia.

Además, tu función de multiplicar es incorrecta; estás multiplicando unos vectores que defines en la propia función (los cuáles estarán vacíos) no los vectores que habías rellenado. Te propongo que la función `parximpar` devuelva un vector y reciba los vectores que quieres multiplicar como referencia constante:

```
vector<int> parximpar (const vector<int> &numerospares, const vector<int> &numerosimpares){

    vector<int> resultado(20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        resultado = numerospares[i] * numerosimpares[i];
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

por que no pasas los vectores por parametro como haces al inicio algo asi, vectorparximpar (numerospares,numerosimpares,paresximpares); para el llamado de la funcion en el main, y en la funcion debes modificar la entrada de parametros asi, parximpar (vector paresximpares,vector numerospares,vector numerosimpares) y eliminar la creacion de los dos vectores dentro de la funcion parximpar ya que los estas definiendo en los parametros de la funcion. Cualquier otra duda con gusto, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

> el vector 1 ingresa num pares

Dado que la función es la que genera la información lo suyo es que la devuelva vía `return`:

```
vector<int> vectorpar()
{
    vector<int> numerospares;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
        if (i % 2 ==0)
            numerospares.push_back(i);
    }

    size_t size1 = numerospares.size();

    for(size_t j = 0; j< size1; j++){
     cout << setw(3)<<numerospares[j]<<endl;
    }

    return numerospares;
}
```

Y algo equivalente para los números impares.

> el vector 3 multiplica cada item del vector 1 con el vector 2

La función `paresximpares`, según entiendo, debería recibir los dos vectores anteriores y generar un vector nuevo con los resultados:

```
vector<int> parximpar (vector<int> const& pares, vector<int> const& impares)
{
  vector<int> resultado;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < pares.size(); i++)
   resultado.push_back(pares[i] * impares[i]);

  return resultado;
}
```

Finalmente yo sacaría el código que imprime los vectores a una función independiente... personalmente odio repetir código. La idea es que los vectores se impriman desde el `main` no desde las funciones generadoras:

```
vector<int> vectorpar()
{
    vector<int> numerospares;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
        if (i % 2 ==0)
            numerospares.push_back(i);
    }

    return numerospares;
}

void ImprimeVector(vector<int> const& vector)
{
  for( int n : vector )
    cout << setw(3) << n << '\n';
}
```

Y con todo esto el `main` nos queda ahora más coherente ya que se entiende claramente lo que hace y no hay sorpresas dentro de ninguna función.

```
int main() {
  vector<int> numerospares = vectorpar();
  vector<int> numerosimpares = vectorimpar();

  cout<<"El arreglo de pares es:"<<endl;
  ImprimeVector(numerospares);

  cout<<"El arreglo de impares es:"<<endl;
  ImprimeVector(numerosimpares);

  vector<int> resultado = parximpar(pares,impares);

  cout<<"El producto de los arreglos es:"<<endl;
  ImprimeVector(resultado);

  return 0;
}
```